# Parametrization of a surface 4

Tags: surfaces

So i have this surface, lets say $S$:

$$(x^2+y^2+z^2)^3=(x^2-y^2)^2, |x|\leq y$$

So i have to change this into a parametric expression.

So, the left side seems something simmilar to a sphere, so i am thinking about using spherical coordinates, but i don't know if it's okay, since there is the right side .
So is this going to work this way, or did i start completely wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
  r &= r(\theta,\phi) \\
  x &= r\sin \theta \cos \phi \\
  y &= r\sin \theta \sin \phi \\
  z &= r\cos \theta \\
  r^6 &= r^4\sin^4 \theta (\cos^2 \phi-\sin^2 \phi)^2 \\
  r^2 &= \sin^4 \theta \cos^2 2\phi \\
  r &= \sin^2 \theta \cos 2\phi
\end{align}

For $|x| \le y$, $$(\theta,\phi) \in [0,\pi] \times \left[ \frac{5\pi}{4}, \frac{7\pi}{4} \right]$$